# How to align input element type checkbox content in center using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align arrow symbol content in center using CSS but it is not working.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contentpanel {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.lowerpanel {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 4em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 30%;
}


/* demo purpose CSS to use input/label to toggle display of lowerpanel */
#hide {
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  background: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, #969696 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 1px #adadad;
}

[for="hide"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #bee;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

#hide:checked~.lowerpanel {
  width: 100%;
}

#hide:checked~.contentpanel {
  display: none;
}

#hide:checked:after {
  content: '>';
}

#hide:after {
  content: '<';
}
```

```html
<div class="app-container">
  <div class="contentpanel"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide">
  <div class="lowerpanel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, [you don't need vendor prefixes for linear gradients](https://caniuse.com/css-gradients). You also don't need the filter fallback.

Comment: This is probably the simplest for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334777/1264804

Comment: The above question actual solution posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78002785/4652706